# Blackberry button click handler

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to run some Java code when the user clicks on this ToolbarButtonField in my BlackBerry app. I have the following code which is not working. Please tell me where I am wrong.

```
butHome = new ToolbarButtonField(new StringProvider("Home"));
butHome.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        System.out.println("Clicked...");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post your second question as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
butHome = new ToolbarButtonField(new StringProvider("Home")) {
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        System.out.println("Clicked...");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

**[ToolbarButtonField#invoke](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/toolbar/ToolbarButtonField.html#invoke%28%29)**

> Performs an action when this
>   ToolbarButtonField is clicked on if
>   Command has been set. A click is
>   defined as the following sequence of
>   touch events: TouchEvent.DOWN,
>   TouchEvent.CLICK, TouchEvent.UNCLICK
>   and TouchEvent.UP.

You're going to have to use that in conjuction with the [Command framework](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/command/Command.html). If that's not desirable, override [ToolbarButtonField#touchEvent](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/toolbar/ToolbarButtonField.html#touchEvent%28net.rim.device.api.ui.TouchEvent%29) for a `TouchEvent.UNCLICK` event to execute the desired code.

```
public boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
  if ( message.geEvent() == TouchEvent.UNCLICK ) {
         // do what I want.
  }
}
```